# Manage playback of audio stream from device to chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I have been searching for the best practice of stopping the playback on a device when the chromecast is selected.  right now I connect to an audio stream, it starts playing on the chromecast fine, but also stays playing on my phone.  I had hoped this was some type of automatic switch that was supposed to occur.  Is it up to me to manage all of this??  If so what are the best practices to start/resume playback when switching back and forth from the chromecast to the device?  It is a live stream so no way to pause and pick up where it left off.

Are there certain callbacks that I need to watch for to make the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is your responsibility to manage the behavior of your app. Our UX Design Checklist outlines the flow that we are recommending; for example when you start streaming to a cast device, you stop the local playback. Details of how you can stop the playback locally depends on your application but what you should use is a set of callbacks that the Android Cast SDK provides for you to learn about the success of your cast control commands and state changes that happen on the receiver. These callbacks can tell you if your launch of application was successful or not, whether the media is playing or paused, or when the metadata for the media has changed. You need to look at our SDK [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/package-summary.html) to see which ones are appropriate for your case. We also have a number of [sample projects](http://github.com/googlecast) that do most of these tasks.